# Clicking Files From Menu Does Nothing

Tags: 14.04, filemanager, pcmanfm

I run `Lubuntu` on my primary machine, but am running `Ubuntu` on a desktop.  I was attempting to set `Pcmanfm` as the deafult file browser and everything seemed to go well.  Using `terminal` I installed no issue, then I executed the below to set as deault

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/nautilus.bak

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pcmanfm /usr/bin/nautilus
```

But now if I click `files` from the menu bar (on the left side of the screen) nothing happens.  What do I need to change so that it will open `pcmanfm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the unity launcher, you will need to make a .desktop file to point to pcmanfm.

The relevant ubuntu help is here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Essentially though, I find it easier to copy a working .desktop file from

```
/usr/share/applications/
```

to

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

and edit it to point to the right place.

The file needs to be of the form:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=x.y
Name=ProgramName
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=/home/alex/Documents/exec.sh
Icon=/home/alex/Pictures/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know if there is a way to achieve that, but I wouldn't recommend to change the default file browser. Tried it onces without luck. Because Nautilus is not only the file browser, but also the desktop etc. If you change it, it will have some unwanted consecuences. If you really want to work with pcmanfm better make a clean lubuntu install, which is based on this file browser. Works great also on older machines.